How can I filter data frame with multiple dependent filtering criteria?
I have searched for an answer over the past two days and can't figure this out. I have tidyverse loaded but can use any solution.
I have a data frame structured like this. These are arbitrary values to use as an example:
dput(infile)
structure(list(Group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D"), Match_ID = c("Id224", 
"", "", "", "", "", "Id456", "", "Id111", "", "", "", "", "", 
"Id908", "", ""), Gene = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4", 
"Gene5", "Gene6", "Gene7", "Gene8", "Gene9", "Gene10", "Gene11", 
"Gene12", "Gene13", "Gene14", "Gene15", "Gene16", "Gene17"), 
    TID = c(692L, 12589L, 966702L, 158L, 222985L, 225187L, 112L, 
    2256L, 658792L, 368800L, 22915L, 692L, 12589L, 966702L, 158L, 
    2256L, 658792L), Species = c("Species A", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "Species B", "", "", "", "", "", "Species K", 
    "", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))

I want to group by the Group column.  Then check if there is one or more values in column Match_ID.  If yes, for all rows with a value in Match_ID, check if the row(s) with the value in Match_ID also have a value in the Species column.  If yes, keep that row. Keep the first row if there is more than one row that has a value in both Match_Id and Species.  If the Group has no value in Match_ID, keep the first row of that group.
The final data frame should look like this with one row per Group:
dput(outfile)
structure(list(Group = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Match_ID = c("Id224", 
"", "Id111", "Id908"), Gene = c("Gene1", "Gene5", "Gene9", "Gene15"
), TID = c(692L, 222985L, 658792L, 158L), Species = c("Species A", 
"", "Species B", "Species K")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

I have been playing around with if/else filtering, case_when() and just general filter() but haven't been able to get the code figured out for this use case.
I have this working partially but it doesn't account for if the first row doesn't have the match or if there is more than one match per group:
outfile <- working %>% group_by(Group) %>% filter(row_number() == 1)

How can I structure my filtering to achieve my desired result?

Could you please share the data with dput() so it is copy/pasteable? dput(working) will create R code to recreate the data, including all the class information, blanks, etc. What you have shared is difficult to import as it's not clear where the blanks/missing values are, and common commands like read.table will throw errors or warnings and may not work well.

I have updated my question to include the dput() of each data frame.

You could accomplish this creating many new columns using case_when/if_else that label data points with TRUE or FALSE depending if they match individual conditions, and then later you will be able to filter easily by checking against those individual conditions. In other words, split the conditions in many columns, then filter based on those new columns.

I think this should work...
I replace the empty strings with NA values, which are sorted to the end. Then we can use arrange() to sort your data by your criteria and keep the first row per group. Finally, convert the NAs back to "".
I'm adding in the original row number as a column and sorting criteria to make sure we keep the original first row in the case of multiple matches.
infile |>
  mutate(across(c(Match_ID, Species), \(x) ifelse(x == "", NA, x))) |>
  mutate(rn = row_number()) |>
  arrange(Group, Match_ID, Species, rn) |>
  slice(1, .by = Group) |>
  select(-rn) |>
  mutate(across(c(Match_ID, Species), \(x) ifelse(is.na(x), "", x)))
#   Group Match_ID   Gene    TID   Species
# 1     A    Id224  Gene1    692 Species A
# 2     B           Gene5 222985          
# 3     C    Id111  Gene9 658792 Species B
# 4     D    Id908 Gene15    158 Species K


This tidyverse solution matches your expected output.
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  group_map(
    function(.x, .y) {
      tmp <- .x %>% 
        filter(Match_ID != "" & Species != "") %>% 
        head(1)
      if (tmp %>% nrow() == 0) {
        tmp <- .x %>% head(1)
      }
      tmp
    },
    .keep = TRUE
  ) %>% 
  bind_rows()
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  Group Match_ID Gene      TID Species    
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>   <int> <chr>      
1 A     "Id224"  Gene1     692 "Species A"
2 B     ""       Gene5  222985 ""         
3 C     "Id111"  Gene9  658792 "Species B"
4 D     "Id908"  Gene15    158 "Species K"

group_map's first parameter is a function.  It applies this function to each group of a grouped data frame.  Its return value is a list of data frames that are the result of applying its argument to each group of the input data frame in turn.
The function that is group_map's argument itself has two arguments.  These are conventionally named .x and .y.  .x contains the data belonging to the current group of the input data frame.  .y is a single row data frame containing the columns (and their values) that define the current group.  I don't use it in this case.
group_map's .keep argument determines whether or not the columns that define the current group are kept in .x or not.  By default, they aren't.
The body of the anonymous function passed to group implements the argorithm you describe in our text.  The first assignment to tmp keeps only the first row of the current group that has non-missing values (strictly "" rather than NA) in the current group.  If this temporary data frame has no rows, it is replaced with the first row of the current group, regardless of what it contains.
Finally, the group-specific data frames returned by group_map are row bound into a single data frame.

I appreciate your thorough explanation.  This solution is equally correct as the solution I selected as the answer.

A step-by-step approach, building filter conditions that depend on each other.
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(fltr1 = if_else(Match_ID != "" & Species != "", T, F),
         fltr2 = if_else(Match_ID != "" & Species == "" & !any(fltr1), T, F),
         fltr3 = if_else(Match_ID == "" & Species == "" & !any(fltr1) & 
                   !any(fltr2), T, F), .by = Group) %>% 
  filter(fltr1 | fltr2 | fltr3) %>% 
  slice_head(by = Group) %>% 
  select(-starts_with("fltr"))
  Group Match_ID   Gene    TID   Species
1     A    Id224  Gene1    692 Species A
2     B           Gene5 222985          
3     C    Id111  Gene9 658792 Species B
4     D    Id908 Gene15    158 Species K


Great answer.  This one is the most 'readable'.  Wish I could select more than one as the chosen answer!

You could accomplish this creating many new columns using case_when/if_else that label data points with TRUE or FALSE depending if they match individual conditions, and then later you will be able to filter easily by checking against those individual conditions. In other words, split the conditions in many columns, then filter based on those new columns.
In the following code, I go step by step following your criteria, creating new columns that label with TRUE or FALSE if the rows met the condition, and in the end we just apply the filters using the "or" operator to keep any row that meets any of the three conditions.
data |> 
  janitor::clean_names() |> 
  group_by(group) |> 
  # check if there are values in mathc_id and in species
  mutate(match_id_true = nchar(match_id) > 0,
         species_true = nchar(species) > 0) |> 
  # check if the row(s) with the value in Match_ID also have a value in the Species column. 
  mutate(values_in_both = if_else(match_id_true & species_true, TRUE, FALSE)) |> #filter by this condition
  # check if there is one or more values in column Match_ID
  mutate(match_id_sum = nchar(match_id) > 0,
         match_id_sum = sum(match_id_sum == TRUE)) |> 
  # If the Group has no value in Match_ID, keep the first row of that group.
  mutate(match_id_n = 1:n(),
         filter_first_no_match_id = if_else(match_id_sum < 1 & match_id_n == 1, TRUE, FALSE)) |> # filter by this condition
  # Keep the first row if there is more than one row that has a value in both Match_Id and Species. 
  mutate(values_in_both_sum = sum(values_in_both == TRUE),
         group_n = 1:n(),
         filter_multiple_group_first = if_else(values_in_both_sum > 1 & group_n == 1, TRUE, FALSE)) |> #filter by this condition
  # perform filters
  filter(values_in_both == TRUE | filter_multiple_group_first == TRUE | filter_first_no_match_id == TRUE)

Output is exactly as you expected:
# A tibble: 4 × 14
# Groups:   group [4]
  group match_id gene     tid species match_id_true species_true values_in_both match_id_sum
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>  <int> <chr>   <lgl>         <lgl>        <lgl>                 <int>
1 A     "Id224"  Gene1    692 "Speci… TRUE          TRUE         TRUE                      1
2 B     ""       Gene5 222985 ""      FALSE         FALSE        FALSE                     0
3 C     "Id111"  Gene9 658792 "Speci… TRUE          TRUE         TRUE                      2
4 D     "Id908"  Gene…    158 "Speci… TRUE          TRUE         TRUE                      1
# ℹ 5 more variables: match_id_n <int>, filter_first_no_match_id <lgl>,
#   values_in_both_sum <int>, group_n <int>, filter_multiple_group_first <lgl>


Replace empty strings with NA,
> infile[infile == ''] <- NA

then you can do it in a one-liner.
> do.call("rbind", by(infile, ~Group, \(x) x[which.min(rowSums(is.na(x))), ]))
  Group Match_ID   Gene    TID   Species
A     A    Id224  Gene1    692 Species A
B     B     <NA>  Gene5 222985      <NA>
C     C    Id111  Gene9 658792 Species B
D     D    Id908 Gene15    158 Species K

